# Poker hand, dynamic programming

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, puzzle, poker

[image]

Please see the question above. I just don't understand how come $f(0,r) =0$. Shouldn't that be $-r$ dollars?

Comment: The player is allowed to stop at any time they wish.  If there are only red cards left in the deck, any further play will cause him to lose money, so obviously he will not want to play any more and will stop immediately.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think you have it reversed; you get money for the red cards. If there are only red cards left, then you will be in the negative if you yield immediately, but there is no reason to stop; let the dealer deal the rest of the deck and you break even, i.e. $f(0,r) = 0$.

Comment: @Arthur,  that make sense to me.

Comment: Also, I believe there's an error in the $E[f(b,r)$, the 5-th last line. The second term should be $r/(b+r) *E[f(b,r-1))]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arthur already explained why $f(0, r) = 0$, but here's another way to frame the boundary conditions if you wanted to keep using the same expression except with black/red removed, depending (Python script):

```
@memoize
def E(b, r):
    if b == 0 and r == 0:
        return 0
    elif r == 0:
        return max(b - r, E(b - 1, r))
    elif b==0:
        return max(b - r, E(b, r - 1))
    else:
        return max(b - r, b / (b + r) * E(b - 1, r) + r / (b + r) * E(b, r - 1))
```

The important thing to note is that the payoff is always equal to $b-r$ if you stop, and $0$ if you just decide to draw all the cards. The $f(0, r) = 0$ shortcut is just optimizing away the unnecessary recursion calls.